# How to create multiple embedded line charts with dynamic range sizes using VBA

Tags: vba, excel

Here is my problem. I managed to create a macro that looks like this:

```
Sub Macro1()
   Range("G17:G36").Select
   ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart.Select
   ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("'Sheet1'!$G$17:$G$36")
   ActiveChart.ChartType = xlLine
End Sub
```

I know this was pretty basic to record but my problem is how to change it and make the range dynamic and conditional. For example when I get to the row 17 I have a value in the cell `D17` that is greater than lets say 200 and a value in E17 greater than 100. This should trigger the beginning of my range. So if `D17>200 AND E17>100` I need to get `G17` as the beginning of the range. As for `G36` (the end of the range) the logic is very similar but this time I would test for a condition like this: `IF F36<64 THEN` get `G36` as the end of the range. 
The should repeat till the end. For example the last row could be at 28000 so I expect a good few of these charts to be created along the way.

Thanks is advance for your help,
Schroedinger.

This is how it looks now and gives me a run-time error explained in my correspondence with EngJon.

```
Sub GenerateCharts()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    'Get the last row
    Dim LastRow As Long
    LastRow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
    Dim endOfRange As Long
    Dim wholeRange As Range
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To LastRow
        If Cells(i, 4) > 0.000001 And Cells(i, 5) > 0.00000002 Then
            'Determine the end of the range
            endOfRange = DetermineRange(i)
            Set wholeRange = Range(Cells(i, 7), Cells(endOfRange, 7))
            NewChart (wholeRange)
            i = endOfRange
        End If
    Next i

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
Function DetermineRange(row As Long) As Long
    Dim LastRow As Long
    LastRow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
    Dim j As Long
    For j = row To LastRow
        If Cells(j, 6) < -0.0000000018 Then
            DetermineRange = j
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next j
    DetermineRange = j
End Function
Function NewChart(rng As Range)
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart.Select
    ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=rng
    ActiveChart.ChartType = xlLine
End Function
```

This is a final solution for me. I hope it helps someone. Big tnx to EngJon and Paagua Grant.

```
Sub GenerateCharts()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim StartCell As Long
    Dim EndCell As Long
    Dim ChartRange As Range
    Dim DataEnd As Long
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim HasStart As Boolean
    Dim HasEnd As Boolean
    'Sets end of data based on the row you are charting
    DataEnd = Cells(Rows.Count, 7).End(xlUp).Row
    'Begin loop to find start and end ranges, create charts based on those ranges
    For i = 1 To DataEnd
        If HasStart Then
            If Cells(i, 4).Value < 0 Then
                EndCell = i
                HasEnd = True
            End If
        Else 'If there isn't a starting cell yet
            If Cells(i, 4).Value > 0.000001 And Cells(i, 5).Value > 0.00000002 Then
                StartCell = i
                HasStart = True
            End If
        End If
        If HasStart And HasEnd Then
            Set ChartRange = ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(StartCell, 7), Cells(EndCell, 7))
            ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart(xlLine, _
                                        Left:=ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(StartCell, 10), Cells(StartCell, 10)).Left, _
                                        Top:=ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(StartCell, 10), Cells(StartCell, 10)).Top, _
                                        Width:=ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(StartCell, 10), Cells(StartCell, 20)).Width, _
                                        Height:=ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(StartCell, 10), Cells(StartCell + 25, 10)).Height _
                                        ).Select
            ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=ChartRange
            HasStart = False
            HasEnd = False
        End If
    Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use your recorded Macro1 as a Function and call it when you need to create a new Chart:

```
Function NewChart(rng As Range)
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart.Select
    ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=rng
    ActiveChart.ChartType = xlLine
End Function
```

You will also need the following function:

```
Function DetermineRange(row As Long) As Long
    Dim LastRow As Long
    LastRow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
    Dim j As Long
    For j = row To LastRow
        If Cells(j, 6) < 64 Then
            DetermineRange = j
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next j
    DetermineRange = j
End Function
```

You will call it in a Sub that iterates over all rows:

```
Sub GenerateCharts()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    'Get the last row
    Dim LastRow As Long
    LastRow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
    Dim endOfRange As Long
    Dim wholeRange As Range
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To LastRow
        If Cells(i, 4) > 200 And Cells(i, 5) > 100 Then
            'Determine the end of the range
            endOfRange = DetermineRange(i)
            Set wholeRange = Range(Cells(i, 7), Cells(endOfRange, 7))
            NewChart wholeRange
            i = endOfRange
        End If
    Next i

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Copy those three in a module and execute the Sub. Please comment if this did what you needed.

Comment: EngJon thank you very much for your prompt reply. I've just got back to it so I'm pretty impressed with your speedy reply. Tnx!

Comment: I have a small problem. If I use values I used to make up the example i.e. the values of D17>200, E17>100 and F36<64 then I can run the code (F5) and everything appears to be fine. I guess that's because it does nothing. But if I use real values then I get a run-time error of 424: Object required and it points to NewChart (wholeRange). This is how it looks like when I put everything together. Please bear in mind that I'm doing this for the first time so it could be something completely trivial. I was hoping to copy the course code here but it's not possible. How to do this so you can see it?

Comment: Ok, I have not tested the code. Wholerange is not an object in NewChart, so that seems strange. I will look over it by tomorrow ;)

Comment: I'm going to add what I did (actually what you did) at the bottom as an answer so you can see it as a whole as I doubt it's something trivial. I'm limited here by the number of characters I can enter. Speak to you tomorrow.

Comment: I was thinking of using the answer but then I got a hint to simply edit my original explanation of my problem so there it is.

Comment: Oh wow ... that error is unbelievably dumb and could only happen in VBA. I edit my answer (only two brackets cause this error). The generated Charts will overlay, keep that in mind

Comment: Do you know how to fix the overlay problem in your code? I tried to use the code from the second answer but my effort is futile (as expected). I'd also like to position my charts in the right place. For example if a condition is met at row 17 I'd like to see the chart's top left-hand corner in I17 or in J17. Thank you for your help.

Comment: The call `ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart(Top:=ChartTop, Height:=ChartHeight)`contains the parameters for the position of the chart. You'd have to play with those parameters to alter the charts position

Answer (score 0):

Here's a slightly different option that performs all of the tasks in a single function.

```
    Option Explicit

    Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim StartCell As Long, EndCell As Long, ChartRange As Range, DataEnd As Long, i As Integer, j As Integer, HasStart As Boolean, HasEnd As Boolean, _
        ChartTop As Long, ChartHeight As Long


    DataEnd = Cells(Rows.Count, 7).End(xlUp).Row 'Sets end of data based on the row you are charting.


    ChartTop = 50
    ChartHeight = 100

'Begin loop to find start and end ranges, create charts based on those ranges.
    For i = 1 To DataEnd
        If HasStart Then
                If Cells(i, 6).Value < 64 Then
                    EndCell = i
                    HasEnd = True
                End If
            Else 'If there isn't a starting cell yet.
                If Cells(i, 7).Value > 200 And Cells(i, 5).Value > 100 Then
                    StartCell = i
                    HasStart = True
                End If
        End If
        If HasStart And HasEnd Then
            Set ChartRange = ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(StartCell, 7), Cells(EndCell, 7))
            ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart(Top:=ChartTop, Height:=ChartHeight).Select
                With ActiveChart
                    .SetSourceData Source:=ChartRange
                    .ChartType = xlLine
                End With
            ChartTop = ChartTop + ChartHeight + 15

            HasStart = False
            HasEnd = False
        End If
    Next

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    End Sub
```

This also makes sure that each chart created by the tool does not overlap the previous chart.

For the sake of space and clarity, I am putting my response to your followup questions here.

Assuming standard row heights and column widths, you can set

```
ChartTop =(StartCell-1)*15
```

to set the top of the chart to begin at the top of the same row as your data, and within the

```
ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart(Top:=ChartTop, Height:=ChartHeight).Select
```

you can add

```
Left:=(X * 48)
```

where X is one less than the column number that you want the chart to be left-aligned to, e.g. if you want the chart to start at the left edge of Column I, X would be equal to 8. However, as far as I can tell, there is no easy way to adjust these values if your row height/column widths is non-standard, e.g. if you have auto-fit your columns to your data.

Comment: Paaqua Grant thank you very much for your also prompt reply. I've just got back to it so I'm also very impressed with your speedy reply.

Comment: I like your solution in a way that charts do not overlap with each other but I was wondering if you would know how to modify it so the chart gets created at a particular range entry point. For example if a condition is met at row 17 I'd like to see the chart's top left-hand corner in I17 or in J17. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Replace "ChartTop= ChartTop + ChartHeight + 15" with "ChartTop = StartCell * 12.75" and put it above the line "ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart..." and it will set the top of your chart to the top of the row where the data range begins.  The only potential problem with this solution is that, depending on how frequently your conditions are met, you may still end up with overlapping charts.